# Can't run emulator in XCode 5

Tags: xcode5, runtimeexception

Just downlaod xcode 5 and i import my project from previous xcode 4, but i cant run my app in emulator, it return

> dyld: Library not loaded:
>   @rpath/DVTFoundation.framework/Versions/A/DVTFoundation   Referenced
>   from:
>   /Users/decky/Downloads/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/momc
>   Reason: image not found Trace/BPT trap: 5

any help?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have the emulators installed from the Xcode updates window, there is likely an update that is available.

This actually happened to me recently, and I needed to download the emulator images from the updater.

Comment: i thought so, and i just copy SDK Emulator present in xcode 4 installation folder, to the new xcode 5, and still no success, maybe i should download new emulator, btw i install xcode5 sepaarted from xcode4 in different location is this alright?

Comment: I personally have had both installed, but only when it was in developer preview mode.  I think you will find that there is little need to use Xcode 4 (have been using 5 since September), as Xcode5 is backwards compatible with previous SDKs.  If it was me, I would certainly download the emulator images from within the Xcode updater.